# Actionbarsherlock + tabs + multi fragments?

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I´ve tried so hard to get actionbarsherlock + tabs + fragments working.

I only can make this set to work as static, I would like to create this like android market app (swipe movement).

I get stuck when you need to inflate a layout with multi fragments inside.

In Support4demos, I got FragmentsTabsPager as example to follow.

Comment: You need to post the code you're having trouble with and your LogCat if any exceptions are being thrown. If you want to swipe between `Fragments` you need to be using `ViewPager`.

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the right libraries to implement what you want.

Basically, a `ViewPager` library is what is missing from you. My suggestions:

**1. ActionbarSherlock**

It's so dead-easy to work with that I won't explain it.

**2. ViewPagerExtensions**

You can find it [here](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions). Download the ZIP files and create a new project from it.

> I only can make this set to work as static, I would like to create this like android market app (swype movement).

Implement `com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.SwipeyTabsView` from this project. There are easy-to-follow examples. it does exactly what you want. There are even other tab styles to choose from (including the new People tab that comes with ICS). Besides, it's very easy to style it to match your app identity.

**3. `FragmentPagerAdapter`**

Finally, that class from the support library (v4).

Good luck, and be free to ask me if you need more help.

---

You don't need to override `instantiateItem` in `FragmentPagerAdapter` if you're using what I suggested. You only need to

1. Provide a constructor with a `FragmentManager` and call the super implementation;
2. Override `getCount` to return the number of fragments in your pager, and
3. `getItem`, **which is what you'll use to return your fragments for creation.**

This is an example from code I have here (a full working, production example). It's an inner class to the activity that implements the pager:

```
static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f;
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            f= new ItemSalesDataFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            f= new DepartmentChooserFragment();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: " + position);
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this pager handles two 'pages', the left displays sales data. The right one allows the user to select which department. Those are returned in the `getItem` method. The proper fragments (you can use whatever Fragments you already have, no modification needed).

As expected, you join all this together by 1) creating an object that instantiate `MyFragmentPagerAdapter`, and 2) setting the adapter to your `ViewPager` object to be that class that you just instantiated. As you can see, its `getItem` method will "give" the pager all the fragments you need. Example:

```
mFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentPagerAdapter);
```

**Of course, there are other things to do, like creating the tab buttons themselves and joining all this to cross-communicate. I suggest looking at the examples provided in the ViewPagerExtensions ZIP file that you download from GitHub. This is just the answer to the question in your comment. As you can see, it's not that much code using this library.**

Comment: I recommend that ViewPagerExtensions library because I liked the generated code, and also because it provides a few different tab types that you can choose from, besides being very easy to style. If you find Rymnel approach limited in what you can do, be sure to try it out.

Comment: thanks, it really helps. Now I need to learn how to inflate two layouts for each position inside: Object instantiateItem(View container, int position), have you any tutorial? thx

Comment: Updated answer to show an example of how you use `FragmentpagerAdapter` to return the fragments you need. If you need any other help, be free to ask.

Comment: I was wondering: how can we combine this with the Lay out support demo? Because I have one tab in which i would like to implement that as well...

Comment: @Jeroen, not sure what you mean. If you be more specific about which layout I could help you. Otherwise, you can always start a more general question to what your problem.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for reply. I will have a look at it first & let you know if I bump into any issues (on which I will create a new question as you say :)).

Answer (score 38):

I actually managed to get this working without anything more than the ABS library and the support library.  Here is my code:

```
public class ActionBarTabs extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
CustomViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
TextView tabCenter;
TextView tabText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mViewPager = new CustomViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Home"),
            ToolKitFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("FujiSan"),
            FujiFragment.class, null);
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
}
```

You load your tab content based on the following.

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Home"),
            YOURFRAGMENTHERE.class, null);
```

This will give you the lovely "swipey tab" effect, as you refer to it, with ABS, the support library and fragments.  ABS really makes this nearly the same as working with the native libraries.  I actually copied this code straight from Googles paging tabs example and modified it ever so slightly for ABS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I could understand that, but my problem is the fragment class, it always crash, could you please share or give me a way how to create this fragment class with 2 or more fragments inside? thx

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Much better than the examples that come with ABS because this gives fragments with the lovely, new ICS tabs as opposed to the ABS example which seems to revert to old tabs when using the fragments

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, this is exactly what I was looking for! There's one thing though I don't seem to understand, what's the "CustomViewPager" good for? It seems to work just fine with the default ViewPager as well.

Comment: Dude .. You are a freaking life saver. I've been banging my head against a brick wall trying to get ViewPager, ABS, and Swipe working. Thanks!

Comment: Wish I could thank you more, I had been implementing an older but VERY similar version of this using a tabhost, resulting in god-awful styling on 2.x devices. This just saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Lots of examples usually throw an exception (`IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first`) when switching back to a previously selected tab.

I like to adapt Google's example with a `FragmentStatePageAdapter` instead of a plain `FragmentPageAdapter`, which will replace fragments for you and solve this error. Normally this will will destroy fragments that it deems can be removed to save space; override `destroyItem(ViewGroup, int, Object)` with an empty block if you want to always hold on to your fragments.

Here's an example:

```
public class ActionBarTabs extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    CustomViewPager mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    TextView tabCenter;
    TextView tabText;
    ActionBar mActionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mViewPager = new CustomViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

        setContentView(mViewPager);
        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setText("Page 1"), 
            YOURFRAGMENT_A.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setText("Page 2"), 
            YOURFRAGMENT_B.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setText("Page 3"), 
            YOURFRAGMENT_C.class, null);
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
            implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext,
                info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    }
}
```

Works well with ABS and is relatively simple to implement.