# ListFragment with viewPager

Tags: android

I am trying to use ActionBar/Viewpager to supply tab support with fragment.  However, the fragment associated with each, I would like it to be a ListFragment.  Here is my relevent code example I got from the effective navigation  example

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

[..]


public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {

                case 0:
                    Fragment fragment0 = new DummySectionFragment();
                    Bundle args0 = new Bundle();
                    args0.putString(DummySectionFragment.TAB_NAME, "Public");
                    fragment0.setArguments(args0);
                    ((ListFragment)fragment0).setEmptyText("EMPTY");
                    return fragment0;
```

[..]

```
  public static class DummySectionFragment extends ListFragment {

        public static final String TAB_NAME = "tab_name";
```

[..]
The problem is, FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem is expecting a fragment.  When I am trying to access the ListFragment's method, it crashed.  Please advise.  thanks

Comment: Similar question, solved : See the answer by op
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255094/how-to-implements-a-listfragment-into-your-project-from-a-sample

Answer (score 0):

change

```
((ListFragment)fragment0).setEmptyText("EMPTY");
```

to

```
 ((DummySectionFragment)fragment0).setEmptyText("EMPTY");
```

the error code means that you try to access subclass method use superclass instance ,
may be the subclass has the method ,but the superclass has not the method ,this is my own idea

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I discussed something similar with a colleague and he said not to use viewpagers as items of a listview because it is total chaos, even if you don't recycle the views the list will freeze on scroll and stuff like that. How he fixed the issue was creating individual viewpagers inside a scrollview, perhaps you can think about that.