# Customizing ActionBar Tabs on Android 4

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-theme, android-actionbar

I'm trying to customize Tabs on my ActionBar. I just want to align tabs to phone screen and make it stretchable for various screens. But all I get is this:

[image]

The code I use for the theme is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">14dip</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Is it possible just decrease the font and get rid off those blue lines?

**Thanks for help in advance.**

P.S.: Also the Button acts weird. The is no text (while it should be)...

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "just want to align tabs to phone screen and make it stretchable for various screens", do you want the tab text to appear always on one row in a tab, with the tab stretching horizontally to make space for the text?

Comment: No, the tab text can be in 2 or 3 lines, but I want the tabs to fill the width of the screen (in portrait, for landscape it's OK as it's now). Look at tab three, you can only see the half of it...First two tabs are too wide and they shouldn't be, so I'd like to lower the font size and tab width to fit it in (I'd like to use some "sort of percentage measure" for tab width (or tabs), rather than fixed one, like px).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:** Use `ActionBarCompat` in the support library.

---

I suggest you use Jake Wharton's [**ActionBarSherlock**](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for two reasons:

1. ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the compatibility library that facilitates the use of the action bar across all versions of Android. This means users running your application on pre-HoneyComb versions of Android will be able to use the `ActionBar` for navigation as well. This is preferable to both the user (since the `ActionBar` is awesome!) and to you (since you don't have to worry about separating the control flow of your application based on whether or not the `ActionBar` will be available. For instance, without a pre-HoneyComb compatible `ActionBar`, you might have to worry about creating multiple `Activity`s for a single screen... one that is optimized for usage with the `ActionBar`, and one that can be run on pre-HoneyComb devices.
2. With ActionBarSherlock, [styling](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) your ActionBar is easy! I could go into detail on how to do it, but the library already comes with a LOT of [sample code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples) that illustrates how to what you are describing above.

Installing/making use of the library is very easy and is almost identical to making use of the normal `ActionBar` provided in the Android SDK (mostly just call `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`). If you have any questions, let me know.

p.s. Also note that `ActionBarSherlock` provides all of the functionalities that the ViewPagerExtensions library provides and more. I would definitely recommend using the former over the latter.

Comment: Jake Worton doesn't suggest anyone to use actionbar sherlock if you're targeting android 4+

Comment: @just_user I wrote this answer over a year before `ActionBarCompat` was released. You should use `ActionBarCompat` instead.

Answer (score 7):

There's a brand new tool to generate the correct 9patch images for the actionbar : http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 4):

I have found using style guides for the tabs to very inconsistent for honeycomb, It was much easier to just inflate a custom view that does want you want.

```
Fragment serivceFrag = new ServicesFragment();
Tab serviceTab = bar.newTab();
TextViewPlus serviceTabTextView =(TextViewPlus)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_item_layout, null);
serviceTabTextView.setText(servicesLabel);
serviceTab.setCustomView(serviceTabTextView);
serviceTab.setTabListener(new TabListenerFragment(serivceFrag,"Service",R.id.MainInfoPaneFragment));
bar.addTab(serviceTab);
```

This to me was much simpler,

Answer (score 4):

Change to:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
     <item name="android:textSize">14dip</item>
     <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're inheriting from the wrong style, try:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

EDIT: also, make sure you use sp instead of dip for font size (14sp)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you use [ViewPagerExtensions library](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions), it give you 5 different styled tabs to you choose from, also the problem that you have to fill tabs in portrait and landscape ,ode for each screen size is already solved in this library.

By the way, if you look inside the library´s code, you can easy theme this yourself.

Also, if you have trouble implementing this with fragment page, look [actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setCustomView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setCustomView%28int%29) method.