# How to switch screens in android using ontouch method?

Tags: android, touch-event

I have multiple screens in my application. and I want to switch the screens when the user slides the screen. i have used dispatchTouchEvent for this and it is switching the screens.But   the problem is that i want that the screens should be flipped when user slides atleast half the screen.Any suggestion. Below is my code..

```
  public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
 {
       int eventaction=event.getAction();
        switch(eventaction) 
        {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          view1.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left));
          view1.showNext();
          break;

          default:
          break;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to achieve, I suggest you use a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Better yet, implement one of the extensions available in [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or [ViewPagerExtensions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions).

The fact that both projects come with full working (and yet simple) examples is just a nice bonus, because even without the examples they are *extremely* easy to work with.

Finally, remember remember:

> Good programmers code, great programmers reuse.

... [or something like that](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/never-design-what-you-can-steal.html). ;-)

Good luck!

ps.: there are a few questions with similar answers if you search Stack Overflow for "[[android] pager](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20pager)" and "[[android] viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20viewpager)". I've posted an answer in this question, but you can also see others (with slightly different focus) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10912602/489607), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10272812/489607) and so on... and I'm not even considering Google.