# Fragment Tabs and with different layouts

Tags: android, fragment, screen-orientation

So it seems that the standard for tabs in android now, is to use a tabhost in a FragmentActivity and then have each tab as Fragment. The issue im having here is, it seems that the whole system of having side-side fragments for same FragmentActivity(tablets or landscape mode) or having one Fragment launch another FragmentActivity with the second Fragment(if its a small device or on rotation) wont work, because you cant have FragmentActivities for each tab. So how do i implement the main advantage point of having Fragments on tabs?

regards,

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have fragmentActivities for each tab.

This is a example for PagerAdapter:

```
public class ExamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ExamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = null;
        switch(position){
        case 0:
        {
        f = new ArrayListFragment();
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            f = new PrincipalFragment();
            // set arguments here, if required
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            f.setArguments(args);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {   
            f = new ViewFragment();
            // set arguments here, if required
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            f.setArguments(args);
            break;
        }   
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: " + position);
        }


        return f;


}
```

}

You can use this to call every activity for each fragment.

```
public class PrincipalFragment extends Fragment {

    private int mNum;
    private EditText et;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    /**
     * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
     * instance number.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scrollview, container, false);



        ImageView i = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          ImageView i2 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

          ImageView i4 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
          ImageView i5 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);


          ImageDownloader.Mode mode = ImageDownloader.Mode.CORRECT;
          ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
          imageDownloader.download(URLnames.URLS[1], i);
          imageDownloader.download(URLnames.URLS[2], i2);
          imageDownloader.download(URLnames.URLS[3], i4);
          imageDownloader.download(URLnames.URLS[4], i5);


        return v;
```

Like the example above, I call the layout scrollview, so when you gonna create scrollview.xml you need to specify the details.

New > android xml file > Select Layout type > Next > Choose a specific configuration ( you can use by density, by orientation and etc... ) > Finish.

Now eclipse will gonna create a different folder for each specific configuration and will manage it own by own when you run different screen sizes or sdkversion.

Read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information.

Don´t know how to implements tabscroll properly? Visit this answer: [Actionbarsherlock + tabs + multi fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments)

Inside the fragment activity you can create a case to select screen-orientation or put it in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Ok thanks i need to check this out tomorrow...but where's the activityFragments, seems this returns fragments with the getItem() method but where do i put this?

Comment: its gonna return fragments, just read my complement and give me an answer.