# Navigation Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing one application where i want to follow latest design guidlines for android. And now i want to use TABS as in 4.0 there is not recommended to use TabWidgets anymore and it is recommended to use Navigation Tabs i checked this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html - At navigation tabs

But i dont realy understand how i am able to do this. Dont know where to include this ActionBar.TabListener etc. Are there any more detailed tutorials for this or does anyone here have any detailed code.

Thank you!

Comment: The link you provided gives examples of how to create a tab listener, and how to attach it to the actionbar?

Comment: you can do this : [HERe](http://arvid-g.de/12/android-4-actionbar-with-tabs-example) or take a look on :
[this link](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/08/29/simple-actionbar-for-android-application/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good example of using Action Bar:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/Usingactionbartabsandhowtheyinteractwithotheractionbarfeatures.htm

Also some good examples here:

[Actionbarsherlock + tabs + multi fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments)

Answer (score 1):

Check this [ActionBarSharelock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and the same thing on [Github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock).