# Using ViewPager in android gingerbread with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

im my application I am using ABS I want to swipe through the tabs ( [Actionbarsherlock + tabs + multi fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments) ) When I use the second answer from this code (just completely copied) it is working fine on my Android 4.0 debugging device but when I test on my GingerBread device it stops. I also imported the support library but it just keep crashing on GingerBread.

I can't provide any logcat with errors because I can't get debugging to work my GingerBread device. And on the Android 4 device it is working fine.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30187): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.safan.e_app/nl.safan.e_app.ABSTabsViewPagerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1007)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:919)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:872)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.setContentView(ActionBarSherlock.java:668)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at nl.safan.e_app.ABSTabsViewPagerActivity.onCreate(ABSTabsViewPagerActivity.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime(30187):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Probably there is no android support library for GingerBread. Try to add this library and rebuild project under ICS SDK.

Comment: My minimum target is set to 7 and buildtarget to 15. Im using actionbarsherlock because it supports a lot of android versions so i can reach about 97% of the market

Comment: it'll be hard to get help without the logs, the problem seems to be ActionBarSherlock, or the way it is being compiled. It works on ICS because ActionBarSherlock allows the phone to use the native menu bar in HONEYCOMB and above but uses its own implementation for Gingerbread and below. But then again it could be your phone (seeing as logcat is broken).

Comment: I found that i can read adb logcat from terminal but i have no idea how to save it and it moves so fast

Comment: try [saving it to a text file](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file)

Comment: http://host03.pipebytes.com/get.php?key=103153503624867 the activity is called ABSViewPager

Comment: @vikki sorry it is called ABSTabsViewPagerActivity