# ActionBarSherlock with navlist: how to save instance of Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a small App with one Activity and a lot of Fragments; I work with SherlockFragment.
My Problem is that I dont know how to save the instance of a fragment to get the last Fragment that appears on a special navlist item.

E.g.:
I choose a navlist item e.g. "info". Then I get FragmentA, FragmentA extends from a SherlockListFragment, so I can choose a ListItem and then I get FragmentB. FragmentB extends also from a SherlockListFragment and so I get FragmentC and so on.

Now the Problem is the following:
When I choose another navlist item e.g. "home" I get FragmentD. 
Now I choose again my navlist item "info" and I want that FragmentC appears.

In my Code-snippet I just replace the Fragments, but I need to know which fragment was shown as last.

My SherlockFragmentActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener{
    private FragmentHome mFragmentHome = null;
    private FragmentInfo mFragmentInfo = null;


    private static final String mListItemHome = "starthome";
    private static final String mListItemInfo = "startinfo";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.My_Theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    // Navlist
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
            R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);

    mFm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //Init of my Fragments:              
    mFragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
    mFragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo();
    }

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = mFm.beginTransaction();
        switch(itemPosition){
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, mFragmentHome);
            ft.addtoBackStack(mListHome);
            ft.commit();
            return true;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, mFragmentInfo);
            ft.addtoBackStack(mListInfo);
            ft.commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
       }
  }
}
```

My Fragments seem like this:

```
 public class FragmentInfo extends SherlockListFragment{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    //disable the HomeButton as "Up"-Button
    ActionBar actionBar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("x", x );
    bundle.putString("y", y);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentInfo fragment = new FragmentInfo(fm);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack("info");
    ft.commit();        
    }
}
```

I really looked the whole day for a solution, but I didn't find soemthing that could help me. 
I think I need something like this for tabs:
[Actionbarsherlock + tabs + multi fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments)
Or something like a TabHost for Lists...

I hope you can help me.

With best regards

**EDIT:**

I just get the Problem with hide and show.
In my xml-layout i've got a Framelayout with the id: fragment_content.
This id was always used to replace one fragment by an other.
Now I add another Framelayout with the id: fragment_info.
I've done this to get the last Fragment that I replaced there with the FragmentManager.

Now, my on NavigationItemSelected Method seems like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = mFm.beginTransaction();
    switch(itemPosition){
    case 0:
       if(mFragmentHome==null){
           mFragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
           ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, mFragmentHome)
           ft.addToBackStack(mListItemHome);
           ft.commit();
       }else{
           if(mFragmentHome.isHidden()){
               ft.show(mFragmentHome);
               ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, mFragmentHome)
               ft.addToBackStack(mListItemHome);
               ft.commit();
           }
           ft.hide(mFragmentInfo);
       }
    case 1:
       if(mFragmentInfo==null){
           mFragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo();
           ft.replace(R.id.fragment_info, mFragmentInfo)
           ft.addToBackStack(mListItemInfo);
           ft.commit();
           ft.hide(mFragmentHome)
       }else{
           ft.hide(mfragmentHome();
           //here I get the last Fragment I choose under the navlist-Item "Info"
           Fragment f = getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_info);
           ft.replace(R.id.fragment_info, f);
           ft.addToBackStack(mListItemInfo);
           ft.commit();
           }
           ft.hide(mFragmentHome);
   default:
   return false;
   }
}
}
```

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But now I have another Problem with my Back-Button.
When I choose Menu Info and browse through FragmentA to FragmentB to FragmentC, then I choose navlist-Item "Home" and again navlist-Item "Info", so I get FragmentC.
But when I now press the BackButton the Activity will destroyed.

But I want that after pressing the BackButton comes FragmentB -> FragmentA and now i can finish the Activity.

I know I can override the Backbutton but I guess I make some mistakes.
Perhaps I should work with detach and attach?
I think there should be a simpler way, isnt't there?

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late.But it will help some others. Use show and hide instead of replace.Here is a sample code.

```
private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:

            if (frag1 == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                frag1 = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(),
                        FeedsActivity.class.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag1, "Feeds");
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.show(frag1);
            }
            return;

        case 1:
            if (frag2 == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                frag2 = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(),
                        ProfileActivity.class.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag2, "Profile");
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.show(frag2);
            }
            return;
        case 2:

            if (frag3 == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                frag3 = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(),
                        History.class.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag3, "History");
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.show(frag3);
            }

            return;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (frag1 != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                ft.hide(frag1);
                return;
            case 1:
                ft.hide(frag2);
                return;
            case 2:
                ft.hide(frag3);
                return;

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```