# how to use ActionbarSherlock & ViewPagerIndicator in android project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

how can i use ActionBar Sherlock and ViewPageerIndicaor ? i want to set Actionbar and tab  indicator , is it possible ? 
tanks

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments

Answer (score 0):

The ViewPageIndicator is an extension for the ViewPager look at both implementations you will see some similar methods, if I recognize it correctly the logical order should be like this:

the viewpageindicator holds the viewpager and the viewpageradapter, so instead of setting the adapter directly on the viewpager you need to set it on the indicator