# Tabs using action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am quite new to the action bar,I want to make simple application using the action bar tabs and fragments by using min sdk 14 and target sdk 16.

this is the Fragment class

```
public class Tab1fragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab, container,false);

    }
}
```

And this is the tablistener class

```
public class tabslistener implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    Fragment _fragment;
    boolean check=true;

    public tabslistener(Fragment _fragment)
    {
        this._fragment=_fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(check)
        {
            ft.add(R.id.Fragment1, _fragment,null);
            check=false;
        }
        else
        {
            ft.attach(_fragment);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.detach(_fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And this is my main class

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar actionbar=getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        Fragment fragment=Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1fragment.class.getName());
        tabslistener tablistener=new tabslistener(fragment);
        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionbar.newTab().setTabListener(tablistener);
        actionbar.addTab(tab1);

    }
```

And this is the errors i got in the logcat

```
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabs/com.example.tabs.NextActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070001 for fragment Tab1fragment{416511c8 #0 id=0x7f070001}
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070001 for fragment Tab1fragment{416511c8 #0 id=0x7f070001}
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:822)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4474)
01-19 01:40:40.078: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
```

Comment: have u check R.layout.fragmenttab created in layout folder becoz this layout cant get by tabfragment

Comment: Take a look here, have good samples and information.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And this is the errors i got in the logcat

The error appears because you try to do a transaction to add a fragment(`Tab1fragment`) to a view that can't be found(the one with the id `R.id.Fragment1`). I don't know if what you posted is the full code but it seems that the view with the id `R.id.Fragment1` is in the `Tab1fragment`'s layout file, `R.layout.fragmenttab`. If this is the case, don't do this, instead you should provide an id to a layout that is already in the `Activity`. For example you could make the content of the `NextActivity` to be a simple `FrameLayout` and use that as the container for the tab's content:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
    fl.setId(1000);
    setContentView(fl);
   //...
```

and use the `1000` id for the fragment add transaction:

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (check) {
            ft.add(1000, _fragment, null);
            check = false;
        } else {
            ft.attach(_fragment);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much :D it works i have spent 3 days trying to figure out what i am doing wrong