# Why wont my regular Tabhost work w. ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

I am pulling my hair out trying to get a simple tabhost to work with ABS, it seems Android only complicates things more when attempting to "improve" them. I was considering converting my project to use fragemnts for tabs , but that proved to be wayyyyyyyyy to much work for the complex layouts im using in each of my tabs. Id settle now for just a plain ol working tabhost w. working abs bar.

```
package com.abs.tabs.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.buhz.feeds.Buhdz;
import com.buhz.login.R;
import com.buhzhyve.localz.Localz;
import com.buhzhyve.trails.Trails;
import com.buhzhyve.trendz.Trendz;

public class FragmentTabs extends SherlockActivity {
    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);


        actionBar=getSupportActionBar();

         Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables

            TabHost tabHost =(TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  // The activity TabHost

            TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab

            Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

            // Do the same for the other tabs

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Buhdz.class);

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Buhdz").setIndicator("Feeds",

                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.buhdz_tab_icon))

                          .setContent(intent);

            tabHost.addTab(spec);

         // Do the same for the other tabs

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Localz.class);

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Localz").setIndicator("Locals",

                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.locals_tab_icon))

                          .setContent(intent);

            tabHost.addTab(spec);



            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Trendz.class);

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Trendz").setIndicator("Trends",

                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.trends_tab_icon))

                          .setContent(intent);

            tabHost.addTab(spec);



            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Localz.class);

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("convos").setIndicator("Convos",

                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.convos_tab_icon))

                          .setContent(intent);

            tabHost.addTab(spec);

         // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Trails.class);

            // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Trails").setIndicator("Trails",

                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.trails_tab_icon))

                          .setContent(intent);

            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            return true;
        case R.id.subItem1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sub Menu item 1 tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.subItem2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sub Menu item 2 tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, but you know that you cannot mix actionbarsherlock and native actionbar?

Comment: All I wanted all along was a working ABS Actionbar and working tabs. If I could get away with using my old tabs w. activitys id be cool with that  (my tab code is almost identical to this: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/ )

If i have to learn and use fragments for my tabs then I need help converting activitys to fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use this library: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator, you can find inside this library some samples with tabs like you want and works with sherlockactionbar.
2. Visit this question: [Actionbarsherlock + tabs + multi fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments).
3. Ask me if you got in trouble.

Comment: Ive got the tabs to work , but now my question is how do I move around through my app if im using tabs + fragments using buttons being that fragments dont play nicely w. intents?  If my user is for instance on a tab 3 (lets call this tab profiles) and they click a image-button thats suppose to take them from their profile to a friends how would I go about that?  Is ViewPageIndicator the commonly accepted default means of switching from tab2 to tab3 using a button inside tab2 ?

Comment: Well, it is possible, have many ways to do that, inside the layout of your fragment you can easily add a button/imagebutton and call an intent, maybe you still not understand how fragments works.