# ActionBar with TabFragments for lower SDK like Android 2.3 and Above in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working in an application in which I have to implement ActionBar with TabListener. I have got a sample code for this task [lucazanini](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tab-layout-in-android-with-actionbar-and-fragment/?lang=en) but this is working only for API 4.1 and Above and Its not working for any lower API's.
Aslo I got a sample for ActionBar with a library project but it does not include TabFragment in it.

Please suggest me with some sample so that I can work on ActionBar + ActionBar.TabListener in Lower API level in Android.

Comment: here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments/10082836#10082836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html) library which is almost a standard for doing such thing by now. Even Google suggests using it.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting...!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActionBarSherlock.

You can find it in http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html.

This library uses native ActionBar for Android 4+, and makes a wrap for older release.
Google is using this library and encourages its use.

You can find source code here:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

In the same repository you can find a lot of examples.

If you want it in action, you can try this free app:Android UI Patterns:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5ncm9pZGlmeS51aXBhdHRlcm5zIl0.

Answer (score 1):

this will be helpful:
[actionBar sherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

it is working fine.,you can override the example for your requirement. it looks simple.