# How to change the fragment of a Tab with a new fragment on the same tab with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I having problem with this awesome library. I have a MainActivity with 4 tabs:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

// Declare Variables
ActionBar mActionBar;
ViewPager mPager;
Tab tab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml

    SharedPreferences pref= getSharedPreferences("wizard", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    String isOkWizard= pref.getString("isOkWizard", null); //prelevo lo stato dello wizard
    if(isOkWizard!=null){
        //abilita tutto
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "" 
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //toggleFullscreen(true);
   // setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_NoActionBar);
    // Activate Navigation Mode Tabs
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Locate ViewPager in activity_main.xml
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Activate Fragment Manager
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Capture ViewPager page swipes
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            // Find the ViewPager Position
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
    // Locate the adapter class called ViewPagerAdapter.java
    ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm);
    // Set the View Pager Adapter into ViewPager
    mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

    // Capture tab button clicks
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    // Create first Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create second Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create third Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

 // Create 4 Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab4").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

}
```

Now in the first tab I have a the Fragment1 with 5 buttons that open a new fragment. My problem is to replace this fragment with the new called from the button listener. This my fragment1 for the first tab:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {

    static Context context;

        @Override
        public SherlockFragmentActivity getSherlockActivity() {
            return super.getSherlockActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml


         //     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
            RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1,
                    container, false);
            context=getActivity();
            Button guasti = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bGuasti);
            Button segnala = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.segnalaDisservizio);
            guasti.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Fragment newFragment = new FragmentTab2();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                    // and add the transaction to the back stack
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                    // Commit the transaction
                    transaction.commit();

                }
            });

            segnala.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(hasConnection()){
                    Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(), SegnalaDisservizioActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Devi avere una connessione attiva per usurfruire del servizio", 3000).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            return view;
        }

        public static boolean hasConnection() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }

            NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            setUserVisibleHint(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have all your 5 fragments are being managed from `ViewPagerAdapter`.

In your activity define a public method like

```
//tabNumber from 0 to 4
public void nextPage(int tabNumber)
{
   mPager.setCurrentItem(tabNumber);
}
```

and from your fragment, call

```
int tab =1; //or any number
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
mainActivity.nextPage(tab);
```

Your fragment will automatically move to the specified number.

I suggest you download view pager demo app from JakeWharton [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample) and the source code for the same [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample) . Next time when you are stuck you can simply check the app for required functionality and learn from the master himself.

**Edit!!!**

If you want to replace the fragment altogether, you should manage that either in the adapter or you shouldn't be using view pager.

For fragment demos, check [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments) and the [source code here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments)

Check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments) matches what you want. In any case, try to make your question as clear as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but if i use my method the new fragment is displaying but there is the old in the back... how can i repair to this?

Comment: In that case you shouldn't be using view pager at all. You should simply load one fragment and keep replacing fragments without adding to backstack. Another way is to over ride the back key in the activity

Comment: I removed the page adapter, but it still remains the problem of the fragment on one another. I am attaching a photo http://i.imgur.com/PiyBtvc.png?1. the red lines are objects of the second fragment...